# How is the adjusted family net income calculated for the Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit (OSTTB)? What is included in that adjustment?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate, calculation

How is the adjusted family net income calculated for the Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit (OSTTB)?

What is included in that adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

An answer at this [closed question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/ontario-hst-rebate-how-to-compute-income-for-phase-out-range/2129#2129) discusses that adjusted net income is likely the net income on line 236 less any *Universal Child Care Benefit* (UCCB) income received. [TaxTips.ca](http://www.taxtips.ca/filing/witb.htm) discusses that this is the method used to calculate adjusted net income for the Working Income Tax Benefit (WITB).

Comment: I did call 1-877-627-6645 and was told that information was not available to the public (whether they want the money back or not).